# How to change label to original text after it's been changed with a function in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a button that changes a text view when it's pressed, I want it to do the changed text to be switched into the original text when the button is pressed again.

My Code:

```
    //An IBOutlet for the textview
    @IBOutlet weak var changingText: UITextView!

    //The button that changed the text
    @IBAction func viewChangedText(sender: AnyObject) {

    changingText.text = "Changed Text"

}
```

Now I want the text changed back when the button is pressed again.

Note: The original text is in in the storyboard, and if possible. could you help me change the button's text to "View" when the original text is there and change the button's text to "Hide" when the changed text is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var didChange = false
        @IBOutlet weak var changingText: UITextView!

        //The button that changed the text
        @IBAction func viewChangedText(sender: AnyObject) {
        didChange = !didChange
        if didChange {
          changingText.text = "Changed Text"
        }else{
          changingText.text = "Original text"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@nathanwhy has a nice idea with the switch-bool. Building upon that idea you could have something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var changingTextView: UITextView!

var showOriginalText : Bool {
    didSet {
        changingTextView.text = showOriginalText ? "original text" : "other text"
    }
} 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // or wherever else it makes sense
    showOriginalText = true
}


@IBAction func changeButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    showOriginalText = !showOriginalText
}
```